# Django websockets with Redis

Tags: python, jquery, django, websocket, redis

I'm using django-websocket-redis (http://django-websocket-redis.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

I can send messages to the global channel but not to a specific user.

### **Following the docs: http://django-websocket-redis.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html**

**Message to the global channel (WORKING):**

Client code:

```
WS4Redis({
    uri: '{{ WEBSOCKET_URI }}foobar?subscribe-broadcast,
    receive_message: function(data){alert(data)},
    heartbeat_msg: {{ WS4REDIS_HEARTBEAT }}
});
```

Server code:

```
redis_publisher = RedisPublisher(facility='foobar', broadcast=True)
message = RedisMessage('Hello World')
redis_publisher.publish_message(message)
```

**Message to a specific user (NOT WORKING):**

Client code:

```
WS4Redis({
    uri: '{{ WEBSOCKET_URI }}foobartwo?subscribe-user,
    receive_message: function(data){alert(data)},
    heartbeat_msg: {{ WS4REDIS_HEARTBEAT }}
});
```

Server code:

```
redis_publisher = RedisPublisher(facility='foobartwo', users=['user1',])
message = RedisMessage('Hello World')
redis_publisher.publish_message(message)
```

No error occurs, simply the user's message never captures it. Why?

Answer (score 0):

```
redis_publisher = RedisPublisher(facility='foobartwo', users=['user1',])
```

This line of code is incorrect.
On your template you must specify some element with attribute `value` and you should be able to change it dynamically. For example take `select` tag:

```
<select id=user>
    {% for user in users %}
        <option value={{ user.username }}>{{ user.username }}
    {% endfor %}
</select>
```

In your JS code create ajax post request, taking both values of user and message ids:

```
$.post("{% url 'yourApp:relatedUrl' %}", {
    user: $("#user").val(),
    message: $("#message").val()
})
```

Both keys `user` and `message` will be available in `request.POST.get('user')` and `request.POST.get('message')` respectively. `request.POST.get('user')`this you will put into `users` list in `RedisPublisher`. BTW, you won't able see you messages. As documentation suggests using `SELF` "magic entity", it doesn't work. To see your own messages and others, put `users = [request.POST.get('user'), request.user]` into RedisPublisher.